# Adding a many-to-many object EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try to add a class of what I call "UserTasting" an exeption is thrown. But I'm not trying to update the User class. I'm only trying to add a relation between the two classes.

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)
>   DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
var userTasting = new UserTasting(){ Tasting = tasting, User = userDb};    
dbContext.UserTasting.Add(userTasting);    
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The class looks like this:

```
public int TastingId { get; set; }   

public Tasting Tasting { get; set; }  

public int UserId { get; set; }   

public User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you used the FluentAPI to configure the relationship?

Comment: ```User = userDb``` im guessing ```userDb``` is coming from a query right? are you using Tacking or No Tracking? Because if you are using No Tracking on your queries / DbContext that would be why. But can't tell from the small snippets above

Comment: It may be that you are not generating an auto-incrementing identity on your main key. Try adding `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the key field definition of `TastingId`